# Links not clickable due to JS return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/r9c0dfrj/)

I'm opeing the dropdown boxes using the 'FOO', 'BOO' items in the navigation bar and I'm closing them when a click event occurs outside using the following code which is working fine.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dd-box', function() {
  // Comment out the return statement below and the links will start working.
  return false
});
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that this is also stopping the links within the dropdown boxes from being visted.

The reason I need this code is because I don't want the dropdown boxes to close when click events happen within them.

I'm trying to avoid using hacks like window.open to force the link from being visited, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  ...
```

[see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9c0dfrj/10/)

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help